# How to make ionic select checkbox value in check when data is included in array?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

how I can make the option checked when the page loaded after getting data from a server?

```
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="interests" multiple="true" (ionChange)="addInterests(interests)">
    <ion-option>Automobile</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Cellphones</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Toys</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your typescript file you will have something like this:

```
private interests: Array<string>;
private interestReceivedFromServer: string;
```

In your html you can do:

```
      <ion-select multiple="true">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let interest of interests" value="{{interest}}" [selected]="interest == interestReceivedFromServer">
          {{ interest }}
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

This would work well.